# Running Python requests consecutively returns old website data

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to determine when a website updates. I've done this by creating two variables and requesting the same site data in each. Then comparing them in a while loop, updating one variable in each iteration of the loop (see code below). The website HTML actually changes every minute, as the time changes on the site. So you would expect the loop to end every minute.

Unfortunately, the site seems to send the same original data for each additional request and therefore the while loop does not exit. In order to reproduce the problem, run the code below a couple of times and then inspect the time in the HTML (origsite[4050:4114]) to see if it's the current time or the time from when you first ran the block of code.

```
import time
import random
import sys
import requests

site = requests.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/").text
origsite = requests.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/").text

n = 1

while (origsite == site): 
    x = round(random.uniform(0.8,1.2),3)
    time.sleep(x)
    origsite = requests.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/").text
    print(n)
    n = n + 1
print("site changed")
```

Is this a known issue with requests? Or is the website sending old information on purpose? I have tried using a VPN to change my IP and it still returns old data. Is there another way to test if a site has changed? Below is an example of it using old data. origsite is storing data from 5min before site data is run.

```
origsite[4050:4114]
Out[94]: b'ime data-timezone-offset="3600"><b>04/06/2018 03:11am</b> <span '

site[4050:4114]
Out[95]: b'<b>04/06/2018 03:16am</b> <span id="time-zone-name">LDN</span></'
```

Comment: What is siteTest ?

Comment: Sorry. Old variable, should be "site"

Comment: When testing from my computer, your code works perfectly well. The site does change.

Comment: @Gelineau, for me it works fine the first time... but then if I run the code a few times it starts to store old values. Did you check the time in the origsite variable? Thanks for helping!

Comment: on my environment, it does change, but the number of seconds between 2 changes is not always the same.


site changed, 120
site changed, 60
site changed, 61
site changed, 156
site changed, 61
site changed, 119
site changed, 59
site changed, 58
site changed, 174
site changed, 73
site changed, 31
site changed, 31
site changed, 31
site changed, 15
site changed, 58
site changed, 58
site changed, 118
site changed, 23
site changed, 29
site changed, 9
site changed, 53
site changed, 31
site changed, 32
site changed, 30
site changed, 120
site changed, 60

Comment: Which is strange, as we know it changes every 60 seconds. Any idea why that would happen? I also think if you inspected the 2 variables each time, you would see that it stores older time values. If you print origsite[4050:4114] and site[4050:4114] in the same way you produced the above results, you would probably see some strange times. Can you think of any other way to check when the site updates? I've tried a number, but they all rely on Selenium/requests and both give the above weird results. Ideally it would pick the update up the second it happens. Cheers

Comment: Any luck? @Gelineau

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there didn't seem to be a Selenium/requests solution. I solved the problem by using Browser from splinter. The adjusted code is below:

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('firefox')
browser.visit(mainUrl + cat)
origsite = browser.html
site = browser.html

n = 1

while (origsite == site): 
    x = round(random.uniform(0.8,1.2),3)
    time.sleep(x)
    origsite = browser.html
    print(n)
    n = n + 1
print("site changed")
```